# How expensive is a XSD validation of XML?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I want to validate large xml files by using xsd schemas in C#.
For a file of 1000 lines of xml code validation takes a long time.

Are there any tips and tricks to validate faster?

Can you post some code examples that work faster with large xml validation?

Edit 1 : I validate like this
[Validating XML with XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943131/validating-xml-with-xsd)

Edit 2: For large files takes more than 10 seconds. And I need the validation to be very fast under a second.

Edit 3: File size is greater than 10 Mb

Edit 4: I am considering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413444/xml-schema-validation-fails-with-memorystream-in-c-sharp) approach too, I want to store xml file in database and xsd too.

Comment: how large is the file (bytes; "lines" is ambiguous), how long is it currently taking, and how are you currently doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are currently loading the entire document into memory, which is expensive *regardless* of validation. A better option is to just parse via a reader, i.e. [as shown here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.validationtype.aspx). The key points from the example on that page:

- it never loads the entire document
- the `while(reader.Reader())` just enumerates the entire file at the node level
- validation is enabled via the `XmlReaderSettings`

Comment: the answer you provided is like the responses from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277595/possible-to-validate-xml-against-xsd-using-code-at-runtime-c , I wonder if the validation can still be much faster

Answer (score 2):

It's reasonable to expect parsing a document with validation to take about twice as long as parsing without validation. But that ratio will vary a great deal depending on your schema. For example if every attribute is controlled by a regular expression, and the regex is complex, then the overhead of validation could be far higher than this rule-of-thumb suggests.

Also, this doesn't allow for the cost of building a complex schema. If you have a big schema defining hundreds of element types, compiling the schema could take longer than using it to validate a few megabytes of data.